# Hibernate Query cache and second level cache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache, querydsl, spring-cache

I have a query cache like this .

`JPAQuery dslQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
    QReview qReview = QReview.Review;
    BooleanExpression where = QReview.review.id.in('123');
    dslQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
    List<Review> reviews = dslQuery.from(qReview ).where(where).distinct().list(qReview );`

All the cache paremeters are correctly setup, so i expect that above list , i.e  `List<Review>`  will be cached?

But then when i do `reviewRepository.findOne('123');` i can see db query getting fired instead of Review with id 123 being taken from cache.

Note: reviewRepository is a standard querydsl repository. which implements `CRUDRepository<Review,String>` Review domain model has Cacheable, Cache annotations set.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A bit later but, it will help if you post your cache configuration.

Can happen that the cache it isn't enabled, or nor properly configured.
It will not be the first time that all is "properly" configured and the cache it's not used by some mistake of forbidden parameter.